# Set exact size of char array using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic, char

I have to read from stdin some characters (i don't know how many of them, but no more than MAX) and I want to store them in an array. Is this code snippet correct?

```
char *c1 = (char*) malloc(MAX * sizeof(char)); //may be too much
fgets(c, MAX, stdin);
int size = strlen(c1);
char *c2 = (char*) realloc(c1, size * sizeof(char));
free(c1);
```

Or is there a more elegant way of determining the right amount of memory to allocate for an array when you don't know how many elements to store?

Comment: So why you would have a int * fro c1 and c2 since you're allocating for array for char. Another thought is you could declare an static array char c1[MAX+1]; instead of calling malloc.

Comment: `char *c2 = (char*) realloc(c1, size * sizeof(char));free(c1);`  : `c1` is  alread released if `c1` and `c2` are different.
 `free(c1)` will be double-free because it is released. also It's not to be released when the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `fgets()`, you probably meant `c1`, not `c`.

You could do it like this (if you insist on using realloc()):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 50

int main() {
  char *c1 = malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
  if(!c1) {
    printf("malloc() failed\n");
    return -1;
  }
  fgets(c1, MAX, stdin);
  int size = strlen(c1);
  char* c2;
  if(c1[size - 1] == '\n') {
    c1[size - 1] = '\0';
    c2 = realloc(c1, (size) * sizeof(char));
  } else {
    c2 = realloc(c1, (size + 1) * sizeof(char));
  }
  if(!c2) {
    printf("realloc() failed\n");
    return -1;
  }
  c1 = NULL;
  printf("Input was: %s\n", c2);
  free(c2);
  return 0;
}
```

Here are some comments:

1. You expect to read a string, thus you should use `char*`, not
   `int*`.
2. Usually, you don't want the newline read by `fgets()` to be kept,
   thus I used `c1[size - 1] = '\0';`, which overwrites it. However, if the user inputs the maximum allowed characters, then there will no room for it, thus we check if a newline was really stored in our buffer.
3. [Do not cast what `malloc()` returns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
4. In the `realloc()`, you should allocate space for the size of the
   string, **PLUS THE NULL TERMINATOR**. That's why it's now `size+1`. However, in the case we overwritten the newline, there is no need for that, since we have already decreased the size of the string by one, thus `size` would suffice.
5. Never forget to de-allocate your memory.

---

However, if I were you, I would print a message warning the user to input `MAX` characters and avoiding the reallocation.

You see, as the [ref of fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) states, the function will:

> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.

So, even if the user inputs more, the program will not crash.

---

As Paul correctly commented, it is a really good idea to use a second pointer, so that if `realloc()` fails, we won't lose our data.

Also note that you should't free `c1`, because this pointer is invalidated and should be set to `NULL`. `c1` will likely point where `c2` points, thus if we free `c1`, then `c2` will be pointing to garbage. Or it could be that the whole block of memory is transferred somewhere else, thus `c1` points to garbage, we are trying to free.

Comment: (1) There's no need to allocate `size + 1` here, since you already reduced the length of your string with `c1[size - 1] = '\0';`. (2) `fgets()` won't put a newline there if the line was larger than the buffer, so you ought to check for it before trying to remove it. (3) "There is no need for a second pointer" - there is, because `realloc()` can fail, and you'll lose your original pointer if you don't have a second. (4) There really ought to be some error checking in here to make it a good answer.

Comment: I had thought only for the second point @PaulGriffiths, but you are right in all four. I updated. Do you like it now? Thanks for the alert though!